# How does BlocProvider.value works with added Event

Tags: flutter, dart, events, bloc, flutter-bloc

**What will happen if An event is added to the bloc being passed inside the BlocProvider.value?**

**Will the event gets added before or after i get to the page?**

**And Is Blocprovider.value an ideal way to avoid adding events to bloc in initState() method?
I'm trying to avoid initstate as I'm listening to Stream of data from firebase (this event need to be called only once).**

[image: streamprovi]

Comment: Your add-method in BlocProvider.value will be called every build. It is not the optimal way. This add-event will be added after the current build.

Comment: What's the best and optimal way to handle this? @Mäddin

Comment: I would do this initialization in didChangeDependencies probably. But I don't know if this is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this,
Using the approach stated above will make the **LoadProductFromStream** event get called even before getting to /opening the **StreamproductPage()**.

To avoid this a simple and efficient approach could be used instead

1. create a wrapper widget
2. create the body (the main widget to display results)
   **Below is an image attached to explain this**
   [image]

Wrapper widget is where the bloc will be created/initialized
and where **LoadProductFromStream**() event will be added to the bloc

> In conclusion

This way we only add **LoadFromStream**() event to bloc when we get to **StreamproductPage**

> Takeaway

BlocProvider(create:(context)=> xyzBloc()) // can automatically close bloc

while
BlocProvider.value() // doesn't close bloc automatically
(i stand to be corrected)